# Adding a child object twice to the parent causing NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have a screen that shows the animals in my farm.  If the user wants to add animals, they can click an "add" button which takes you to another screen which lists the animal names.  If the user chooses "dog", my app will query the database and return me a Dog object and I add it to my collection of animals in my Farm entity.

In the above situation, if I were to save the Farm entity, the Farm would be successfully persisted as expected.

However, if the user adds a "dog" to the farm and then decides to add a "dog" again, the saving of the Farm entity results in:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

Now that makes sense obviously because the user has chosen "dog" twice resulting in my app *digging* up two instances of the "dog".  What is the best way to deal with a situation like this?

**Edit:**  Let me clarify, the animals aren't attached to the Farm directly.  The Farm will hold a collection of AnimalShelters which each can house an animal.  The AnimalShelters are unique and given their own identifiers.  I suppose you could think of the "dog" as a privileged dog who could gallivant between multiple shelters.

**Edit:**  Here is the flow of how things are working:

- 1st screen shows the Farm.  There are no AnimalShelters.
- User clicks on the "add" button to add an AnimalShelter
- The new screen has a table of Animals that exist in the database
- The user chooses dog which is found in the database using a 'find' [This is done within a transaction]
- A new AnimalShelter object is created
- The Dog is set on the new AnimalShelter
- The user then chooses to "add" another AnimalShelter containing the same Dog (repeating the previous 5 steps)

**Edit:** Maybe me explaining it in pseudo code might make my problem a little clearer:

- Open Session
- Begin Transaction
- Animal animal1 = session.get(Animal.class, 1L);

  Commit Transaction

  Link animal1 with new AnimalShelter which we link to the Farm

  Begin Transaction

  Animal animal2 = session.get(Animal.class, 1L); *// this returns a different instance of the same Animal compared to the Animal in line 3 which makes sense since we are in a different transaction.  But is there a way to get this to give me the same Animal instance even though I am in a different transaction?*

  Commit Transaction

  Link animal2 with new AnimalShelter which we link to the Farm *// Now there are two animal shelters which I want to point to the same Animal*

  Close Session

**Edit:** Here is the schema:

```
+---------------+
| Farm          |
+---------------+
| Id (pk)       |
| Name          |
+---------------+

+---------------+
| AnimalShelter |
+---------------+
| Id (pk)       |
| AnimalId      |
| FarmId        |
+---------------+

+---------------+
| Animal        |
+---------------+
| Id (pk)       |
| Name          |
+---------------+
```

**Edit:** Stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.spike.model.Animal#1]
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:637)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:451)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:127)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:376)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:344)
at $Proxy14.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.spike.ui.SaveFarmActionListener.actionPerformed(SaveFarmActionListener.java:29)
```

**Edit:** From the comments I have received, my flow now looks like this which is still causing the same exception to be thrown:

- Open Session
- Begin Transaction
- Animal animal1 = session.get(Animal.class, 1L);

  Link animal1 with new AnimalShelter which we link to the Farm

  Animal animal2 = session.get(Animal.class, 1L); *// this now returns the same instance of the Animal as above*

  Link animal2 with new AnimalShelter which we link to the Farm *// Now there are two animal shelters which I want to point to the same Animal*

  Commit Transaction *This statement still throws the exception despite the fact that I can see it is pointing to the same Animal instance*

  Close Session

**Edit:** Interestingly, now that I have everything in the one transaction, it seems to fail with the same exception now even if I only add one Animal.  The reason for this seems to be because when I go to the 2nd screen, it queries for all available Animals - one of them of course being the Dog.  When I add only one AnimalShelter containing the Dog and try to save, it will throw the same exception because I'm assuming it has been loaded into the session already by the 2nd screen which displayed all of the available Animals.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I think I've just obviously done something extremely silly in my swing app.  I'm not entirely sure where I've done this stupidity, however, I have written a standalone app that mimics everything I have outlined in this post so far and everything works fine and I don't get any exception. Obviously somewhere in the midst of all the action listeners, dialogs etc I have done something incorrectly which would be too hard to explain here, but thanks again!  It has really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the dog should be privileged enough to make a relationship with AnimalShelter. Precisely, there should be a one-to-many relationship between `Animal` and  `AnimalShelter`.

Overriding `equals()` for example.

```
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if ( this == that ) return true;
    if ( !(that instanceof Dog) ) return false;
    Dog dog = (Dog)that;
    // Assuming id is of Long type
    return this.id.longValue() == dog.id.longValue();
}
```

And **don't forget** to override `hashcode()`.

Comment: Even if that were the case, how would I ensure I am using the same "dog" when I'm adding it to multiple AnimalShelters?  If the user goes to the secondary screen and chooses "dog" a second time, how do I ensure my handle to the "dog" object is the same "dog" object when I added it to an AnimalShelter the first time?

Comment: @digiarnie: I am not sure I understand the flow/logic fully here. But this is my take. If the user chooses a new `dog`, then it must be a new `instance` of Dog. Otherwise user must have chosen a existing `dog`, in that case we just need to add the reference of that particular `dog` in `AnimalShelter`.

Comment: @Adeel: Yes this is all true. However, once I retrieve the first Dog from the database and associate it with an AnimalShelter, the user can then choose the same Dog again on the secondary screen.  I don't want to have to iterate through all the AnimalShelters just to see if there is a Dog with the same key to attach to the new AnimalShelter.

Comment: @digiarnie: In that case just don't instantiate a new `Dog`. Just retrieve that `Dog` from the database using `id` and associate that with that `AnimalShelter` object. You need not iterate over anything.

Comment: @Adeel: That's what I'm doing (see my response to Jim).  It seems to get into trouble because even though I'm in the same session, I am getting the Dog using find in a different transaction which seems to return me a different instance of the same Dog. (I am never instantiating any Dog object, it is always done using session.find(Animal.class, 1L) assuming 1L is the @id of the Dog.

Comment: @digiarnie: Aha... then you should override `equals()` and `hashcode()` method of your entities generally, and `Dog` particularly. Simple ain't it.

Comment: @Adeel: I already have equals() and hashCode() in the Dog class but it makes no difference -  I get the same exception.  I ran in debug mode and it never hits either the hashCode() or equals() methods. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but not sure what it is.

Comment: digiarnie: Okay tell me why you need to retrieve the `Dog` again, when actually its already there in the session, most probably attached with the `AnimalShelter`.

Comment: @Adeel: As described in my 2nd edit in the original post, it all has to do with switching between screens. The user is originally on the Farm screen. They go to a 2nd screen which has a list of animals available to them. They choose "dog" which is associated with a new AnimalShelter which is set on the Farm object. User then decides to add the same "dog" to another AnimalShelter via the 2nd screen. I shouldn't need to know that the same "dog" was already added to the 1st AnimalShelter. All I know is that the user has selected "dog" from the DB to be associated with another (2nd) AnimalShelter.

Comment: @digiarnie: Please list down the constraints of `ANIMAL_SHELTER` table, especially unique and pk.

Comment: @Adeel: See edit in OP. Nothing terribly interesting. An AnimalShelter belongs to a Farm.  The AnimalShelter can shelter one Animal.

Answer (score 1):

The exception says it all:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

It sounds like what happened is that you are introducing two objects of the same entity class (which I guess is `Dog`?) to the EntityManager that both have the same primary key. This isn't allowed.

If you are creating new `Dog` entities (by creating new instances and invoking `em.persist()` on each one), then make sure you are not accidentally using the same primary key value twice. That is the same as trying to do two native SQL INSERT statements with the same primary key value. I'm guessing that this is your problem. **How does your application assign new primary key values to new entities?** You might find that primary key generation is not working as expected.

If you are working with existing `Dog` entities, then make sure your entities are "managed" and not "detached". You can re-attach a detached entity by calling `em.merge()` on it and then working with the returned (and managed) entity instance from the `merge()` call. I don't think this is your problem, because you would likely have gotten a detached entity exception of some kind rather than the "non-unique" exception.

**To answer your comment question left on the other guy's answer:**

> how do I ensure my handle to the "dog"
>   object is the same "dog" object when I
>   added it to an AnimalShelter the first
>   time?

Call the EntityManager find() method, as so:

```
em.find(Dog.class, myDogPrimaryKeyValue)
```

This will return an instance of Dog that is "managed" by this particular EntityManager. Each EntityManager is **guaranteed** to return the same instance of `Dog` each time you call `find()` with the same primary key value. Just be careful that you do not try to use an entity instance that was returned from one EntityManager on a different EntityManager. An entity is only managed by the EntityManager that originally returned the entity to you, not any EntityManager. See my comments above on using `merge()` to get a managed instance when you start with a non-managed (A.K.A. "detached") instance. You can find out if an entity instance is managed by a particular EntityManager by calling `em.contains()` on the entity.

**EDIT:**

Based on the new information in the question edits, this appears to be a problem with crossing transaction boundaries. Can you keep your transaction open for the full duration of the session rather than doing a commit and then creating another one? This would likely solve your problem. Alternatively, you could use an application-managed EntityManager so that your persistence context will survive for the duration of your session.

Comment: It looks like the entity manager only returns the same Dog instance if the find is done in the same transaction.  When retrieving the Dog twice, this is happening in different transactions but in the same session & therefore it is returning a different Dog despite using the same key to find it.  As a test, I just did a find for the same primary key in the same transaction and it did as you said.  But in my situation, the finding of the same Dog is done over different transactions. Can the same Dog be returned over separate transactions?

Comment: furthermore, I tried calling session.merge(dog); right after calling 'find' on my dao and using the returned dog from the merge call but that gave me the same exception.  So the code for retrieving the dog now looks something like: beginTransaction(); Animal animal = animalDao.find(id); Animal merged = (Animal) session.merge(animal); commitTransaction(); return merged;

Comment: This is one of the scenarios that I thought you might be experiencing. If your work is crossing the boundaries of a transaction, then you cannot rely on object equality as you have discovered. Can your application logic simply use the primary key to determine equality rather than object equality? What Adeel is suggesting is basically the same thing, but he is recommending that you implement the object equality logic manually by making it use the primary key. The only other option that I can think of is for you to change the way you manage your transactions.

Comment: Can your application logic simply use the primary key to determine equality rather than object equality? <-- I'm a little confused by this.  Would you be able to provide an example knowing that equals()/hashcode() do not seem to be invoked? I think I will have to think a bit harder in regards to how to structure my code if the only way to get around this problem is to perform everything in a large transaction. I will have to find the right place to start the transaction and the right place to commit it. Essentially the user goes into 'edit' mode and can do a large number of different actions.

Comment: I don't know how you have things wired in your application, but it is possible to configure it such that your EntityManager is application managed and will survive for the lifespan of a session. This can be done in a Java EE application by storing the EntityManager in a stateful session bean, or in a web application (like one hosted in Tomcat without a full Java EE container) by stored in the EntityManager in the HTTPSession object. You don't need to keep the transaction open, just keep the session alive. As long as the EntityManager lives, so does the persistence context.

Comment: 'm actually writing a swing app so at the moment, the session stays open for the entire life of the application itself so that isn't a problem. I think the way around this is to ensure the transaction has not ended while the Farm is being edited which I think isn't so bad since the adding of AnimalShelters is all done while the user is in 'Edit' mode so I'll just use the single transaction while the user is editing instead of having micro-transactions for every action they perform while editing a Farm.

Comment: hmm..funnily, I've changed my code such that when the user is "editing" a Farm they are within the one transaction the entire time and the Animal instance being returned is now the same (i.e. memory reference is the same) however when I save, I still get the same exception

Answer (score 1):

I have finally gotten it to work.  Just to summarize the things I got from the answers and comments to get it to work:

- When doing a big edit of the Farm, all the little actions of finding Animals, associating Animals to the AnimalShelter, associating the AnimalShelter with the Farm was done in a SINGLE transaction.  This allowed for multiple retrievals of Animals and ensuring that the same instance of the Animal was returned from the session;
- equals()/hashCode() were not called at all in the Animal entity class
- merge() also as not part of the final solution
- At first I tried doing session.evict(...) on the 2nd screen to ensure that the searching of Animals wasn't causing the uniqueness exception
- Along with the transaction thing, the other big part of the problem that was actually causing the exception was the fact that I had bi-directional relationships in my model.  I had the cascade type of ALL set on these relationships.  Cascade type of ALL made sense in most cases when it was a link between parent to child.  But I also had the link back to the parent with cascade ALL.  As soon as I removed those useless (and ultimately) incorrect cascade attributes on the mapping annotations, the exception went away!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Your last step save my day! Im still not sure why is this causing a problem. In my case, it happens only if the child object is updated. I really hope to get the explanation out of this